# Mnemonic private key and final address for a token like BSC (Binance Smart Chain)

Tags: ms-access, vb6, private-key, chilkat, hmacsha512

Based on Chilkat team's functions, I progressed to generate BIP32 Root Key code, but to continue and generate receive address and public private code, I don't know how to do it. I tried many codes in the program, but the tutorials confused me and I don't know how to proceed. How to pass! Based on the website https://iancoleman.io/bip39/, the generation of the final address and private code is as follows:
[image: https://iancoleman.io/bip39/]

In the functions of the Chilkat team, there are many things for generating private and public keys, such as generating BIP44, Derivation Path, and Derived Addresses, but I don't know how to use them:

```
Private Sub CMD_BIP32RootKey_Click()
Dim crypt As New ChilkatCrypt2
Dim mnemonic As String
Dim crypt As New ChilkatCrypt2
Dim mnemonic As String
mnemonic = TXTDEC
Dim passphrase As String
passphrase = ""
Dim expectedSeed As String
expectedSeed = ""
Dim expectedMasterKey As String
expectedMasterKey = ""
Dim bdSalt As New ChilkatBinData
success = bdSalt.AppendString("mnemonic", "utf-8")
success = bdSalt.AppendString(passphrase, "utf-8")
Dim computedSeed As String
computedSeed = crypt.Pbkdf2(mnemonic, "utf-8", "sha512", bdSalt.GetEncoded("hex_lower"), 2048, 512, "hex_lower")
computedSeed = crypt.Pbkdf2(mnemonic, "utf-8", "sha512", bdSalt.GetEncoded("hex_lower"), 2048, 512, "hex_lower")
Dim bdSeed As New ChilkatBinData
success = bdSeed.AppendEncoded(computedSeed, "hex_lower")
crypt.EncodingMode = "hex_lower"
crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha512"
success = crypt.SetMacKeyString("Bitcoin seed")
hmacSha512_hex = crypt.MacBdENC(bdSeed)
Dim bdHmac As New ChilkatBinData
success = bdHmac.AppendEncoded(hmacSha512_hex, "hex_lower")
Dim bdXprv As New ChilkatBinData
success = bdXprv.AppendEncoded("0488ade4", "hex_lower")
success = bdXprv.AppendEncoded("000000000000000000", "hex_lower")
success = bdXprv.AppendEncoded(bdHmac.GetEncodedChunk(32, 32, "hex_lower"), "hex_lower")
success = bdXprv.AppendByte(0)
success = bdXprv.AppendEncoded(bdHmac.GetEncodedChunk(0, 32, "hex_lower"), "hex_lower")
crypt.EncodingMode = "hex_lower"
crypt.HashAlgorithm = "sha256"
Dim bdHash As New ChilkatBinData
success = bdHash.AppendEncoded(crypt.HashBdENC(bdXprv), "hex_lower")
Dim secondHash As String
secondHash = crypt.HashBdENC(bdHash)
success = bdHash.Clear()
success = bdHash.AppendEncoded(secondHash, "hex_lower")
success = bdXprv.AppendEncoded(bdHash.GetEncodedChunk(0, 4, "hex_lower"), "hex_lower")
Dim computedMasterKey As String
computedMasterKey = bdXprv.GetEncoded("base58")
TXTBip32RootKey = computedMasterKey
'???????????
Dim fortuna As New ChilkatPrng
entropy = bdXprv.GetEncoded("base58")
success = fortuna.AddEntropy(entropy, "base64")
Dim ecc As New ChilkatEcc
Dim privKey As privateKey
Set privKey = ecc.GenEccKey("secp256r1", fortuna)
success = privKey.SavePkcs8EncryptedPemFile("pemPassword", "myPemFiles/eccKey123.pem")
MsgBox privKey.GetXml() '?!?!?!
End Sub
```

The Python code for creating the ethereum address from mnomenic on the site https://github.com/kigawas/python-bip44 is as follows. Is it possible to execute the equivalent of the vb6 code in Chilkat? :

```
>>> from coincurve import PrivateKey
>>> from bip44 import Wallet
>>> from bip44.utils import get_eth_addr
>>> mnemonic = "purity tunnel grid error scout long fruit false embody caught skin gate"
>>> w = Wallet(mnemonic)
>>> sk, pk = w.derive_account("eth", account=0)
>>> sk = PrivateKey(sk)
>>> sk.public_key.format() == pk
True
>>> get_eth_addr(pk)
'0x7aD23D6eD9a1D98E240988BED0d78e8C81Ec296C'
```

I would like to thank the friends who can help with the address and the final private key

Comment: that VB6 code is really hard to read without any indenting